# Is there a way to configure amplify CLI with out AdministratorAccess will it work (for a android project)?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify-sdk-android

I am working on a POC where I am trying to use AWS resources like S3, pinpoint, etc in a mobile Android project.
As per AWS latest recommendation i am using Amplify CLI framework in my Android project to integrate Android with my AWS services.
For this as per the doc - https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/project-setup/prereq/q/platform/android#option-2-follow-the-instructions I raised a request to my AWS admin team to create a IAM account with AdministratorAccess, but they refused the request for  various reasons.

Can I achive this is any other way - is there any other way to configure amplify CLI with out AdministratorAccess and will it work?

Step mentioned in doc  - ***"Create a user with AdministratorAccess to your account to provision AWS resources for you like AppSync, Cognito etc."***

Note -  I tried skipping this part and just providing a access key and secret key of account(which dosent have AdministratorAccess,  but Amplify.configure(getApplicationContext()); line failed in my android app without any error/exception -probably Auth error?)

Comment: Can you share the specific error you are getting from `Amplify.configure(getApplicationContext());`?

Comment: hi Richard thanks for the response I dint get any error from  Amplify.configure(getApplicationContext()). I lated identified this is due to gradle sync issue closing this as it not a issue I reposponded here - .https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues/1174. This question can be closed